# 18.04 LTS Login freezes without any login controls

Tags: 18.04, login, freeze

Dear community of this wonderful OS,
since 3 days I try to re-animate my virtual machine on which I do all my work, but have not been successful. I desperately need help on this one.

Here is what happened:
I installed updates via the desktop update gui after it reported that there are new updates and rebooted my virtual machine. However it completely gets stuck on the login screen since then. I can see the login screen with the "ubuntu" text on the bottom, however there are no login controls (like user selection or password entry field).
It is completely frozen because trying to hit ctrl-shift and any of the F-keys does not take me to the terminal. The interesting thing however is that if I send the shutdown command via my vmware workstation (version 15.1.0 build-13591040) I can see a regular shutdown with stopping all services, which appears odd to me.
Booting into the previous kernel via the boot menu leads to the same result.

I googled for similar issues and tried many things, which were recommended. For example I launched also from a live-cd, mounted my filesystem in and checked for broken packages. This did not help. I also forcefully reinstalled several packages both via apt and snap. Mainly packages where errors were reported in the log file. No success. The most promesing looked snap because it was indicating at snap list that all packages are broken. I refreshed all of them (from the command line of the safe boot), but the result was still the same.

I also reinstalled the gvfs package as that one is reported in association with all these G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE error messages.

The log file contains multiple errors, but some might have been there even before this problem appeared. So I am not sure which error message is related to this problem.

Thank you so much for your help and your contribution to this wonderful OS.
Sincerely,
Henry

PS: Due to size limitations, I'm uploading here just the end of my syslog:

`Jun 16 21:00:35 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun 16 21:00:38 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:00:48 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 35 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:00:48 ubuntu nautilus[6930]: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: »net usershare« gab den Fehler 255 zurück: mkdir failed on directory /var/run/samba/msg.lock: Keine Berechtigung#012net usershare: cannot open usershare directory /var/lib/samba/usershares. Error Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden#012Please ask your system administrator to enable user sharing.
Jun 16 21:00:50 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:00:52 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 3 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:01:22 ubuntu gnome-shell[4436]: Some code accessed the property 'discreteGpuAvailable' on the module 'appDisplay'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Jun 16 21:01:22 ubuntu gnome-shell[4436]: Some code accessed the property 'WindowPreviewMenuItem' on the module 'windowPreview'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Jun 16 21:01:24 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:01:24 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:01:25 ubuntu dbus-daemon[1179]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.97' (uid=999 pid=6930 comm="/usr/bin/nautilus --gapplication-service " label="unconfined")
Jun 16 21:01:25 ubuntu systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun 16 21:01:25 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:01:25 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:01:25 ubuntu dbus-daemon[1179]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun 16 21:01:25 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun 16 21:01:27 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:01:29 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 3 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:02:05 ubuntu nautilus[6930]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:07 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:09 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 3 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:02:22 ubuntu nautilus[6930]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:22 ubuntu nautilus[6930]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:24 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:26 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 3 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:02:26 ubuntu nautilus[6930]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:26 ubuntu nautilus[6930]: message repeated 2 times: [ gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed]
Jun 16 21:02:28 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:30 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 3 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:02:36 ubuntu nautilus[6930]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:38 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:02:40 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 3 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:02:57 ubuntu systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jun 16 21:02:59 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:03:01 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 3 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:03:04 ubuntu nautilus[6930]: gtk_widget_set_sensitive: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
Jun 16 21:03:06 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed
Jun 16 21:03:08 ubuntu gvfsd-metadata[4760]: message repeated 3 times: [ g_udev_device_has_property: assertion 'G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device)' failed]
Jun 16 21:03:17 ubuntu gsd-color[4555]: unable to get EDID for xrandr-Virtual1: unable to get EDID for output`

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it to work again!!!
For anyone running into the same issue, I found the solution here:
[Bug 1832138](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1832138)

My solution was to boot into the secure shell (hitting ESC during booting) and from the terminal I installed a newer kernel:

```
apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```